# Строки и группы символов c++

Tags: c++, строки

Есть такое задание :

> Дан текст, каждый символ которого может быть малой буквой, цифрой или
>   одним из знаков +,-,* *. *Группой букв будем называть такую
>   совокупность последовательно расположенных букв, которой
>   непосредственно не предшествует и за которой непосредственно не
>   следует буква. Аналогично определим группу цифр и группу знаков. Если
>   в тексте больше двух групп букв, то между первой и второй группой букв
>   + заменить на 1, - на 2,* * *на 3, иначе оставить без изменений.

Я почти всё поняла. Кроме одного - как найти эти самые группы букв? Перебором строки с помощью цикла, да, но как понять, что это первая, а это вторая группа?

Comment: Ну, мне кажется всё просто. Сканируете строку по одному символу. Сначала ищете первую букву. Она и все буквы, которые идут за ней — первая группа. Всё, что после неё и до следующей буквы, подлежит замене.

Comment: покажите текст чтоб понятней было

Comment: Текст вводится пользователем с клавиатуры.

Comment: Спасибо, надо так попробовать.